# How to pass a list to the SQL query in django

Tags: python, sql, django

Am using the code below:

```
def internal(request):

try:
    year=''
    month=[]
    class=[]
    results=[]
    conn = connections["connection1"]
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    year = request.GET.get('year')
    print(year)
    month = request.GET.getlist('month[]')
    for i in month:
        print("Months::"+i)
    class = request.GET.getlist('class[]')
    response_list = []
    cursor.execute(" select Year,month,student_name,admission_date,class from admission_table\
    where MONTH(admission_date) in ('"+(month)+"') AND YEAR(admission_date) in ('"+year+"') AND class in ('"+class+"') ")

    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)
    if rows:
        for row in rows:
            response_list.append({'year':row[0],'month':row[1],'student_name':row[2],'admission_date':str(row[3]),'class':row[4]})
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_list))
```

How to pass a month and class values which are lists to SQL query.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Can I ask why don't you using Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you executing raw SQL? Instead of `admission_table`, write a model with the attributes year, month, student_name, admission_date, class. Then, use Django's built in ORM to create new objects for the table. All you need to do is loop over the get request's month and class values, and call `AdmissionTable.objects.create(<attributes here>)`.